# Azure Dev Ops Configuring an IIS 3rd level Site

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to configure an IIS Web Application In Azure Dev Ops / VSTS which has a website at level 3, for example

Sites/Applications/payroll-forms/hub-manager

Applications is a Website
payroll-forms is a was a virtual directory but is now an Application
hub-manager is a application

Here is my Variables and YAML

```
Configuration type : IIS Web Application
Website Name : applications
Virtual Path : '/payroll-forms/hub-manager'


steps:
- task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
displayName: 'IIS Web App Manage'
inputs:
  IISDeploymentType: '$(Parameters.IISDeploymentType)'
  WebsiteName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
  WebsitePhysicalPath: 'f:\Websites\Applications'
  AddBinding: '$(Parameters.AddBinding)'
  Bindings: '$(Parameters.Bindings)'
  CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: true
  AppPoolNameForWebsite: Applications
  DotNetVersionForWebsite: v2.0
  PipeLineModeForWebsite: Classic
  ParentWebsiteNameForVD: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
  VirtualPathForVD: '$(Parameters.VirtualPathForApplication)'
  ParentWebsiteNameForApplication: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
  VirtualPathForApplication: '$(Parameters.VirtualPathForApplication)'
PhysicalPathForApplication: 'F:\Websites\Applications\payroll-forms\hub-manager'
AppPoolName: '$(Parameters.AppPoolName)'

steps:
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
inputs:
  WebSiteName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
  VirtualApplication: 'hub-manager'
  TakeAppOfflineFlag: True
  XmlVariableSubstitution: True
```

The Error

```
2019-07-31T14:49:46.1783681Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list app "applications/payroll-forms/hub-manager"
2019-07-31T14:49:46.2584534Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  add app /site.name:"applications" /path:"/payroll-forms/hub-manager" /physicalPath:"F:\Websites\Applications\payroll-forms\hub-manager"
2019-07-31T14:49:46.3231472Z ERROR ( message:Failed to add duplicate collection element "/payroll-forms/hub-manager". )
2019-07-31T14:49:46.4988608Z ##[error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '183'.
```

2019-07-31T14:49:46.5431004Z ##[section]Finishing: IIS Web App Manage

I have tried many combinations and struggling to find an example even though i got a 2 level one working fine.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does change the value of  `/path`  can solve this error message?

Comment: Did you fixed this issue already?

Answer (score 0):

> [error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '183'.

The error code `183` means sorry this files already exists, so I could not create this file since that.

And also, this message can be validate by the previous error message:

> ERROR ( message:Failed to add duplicate collection element
>   "/payroll-forms/hub-manager". )

So according to this message, the issue occurred between `Virtual Path : '/payroll-forms/hub-manager'` and `/path:"/payroll-forms/hub-manager"`. Please try with run this script by **removing** Virtual Path. Or, please change `/path:"/payroll-forms/hub-manager"` as another path value which will not conflict with the value of `Virtual Path`

Comment: Virtual path is required in azure devops.